# Discord.py Rewrite pass list into commands

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a Discord bot using Python 3.9.6 and Discord.py. I am working on a cog with 2 commands; one to message a random string from a list outside of the function, and the other to add a string to the list of messages. When I try to pass in the messages variable everything seems fine, but when I test the command in Discord this error message comes up:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: messages is a required argument that is missing.
```

I think this means that the bot was expecting `messages` to be given by the user, so I tried removing the `messages` argument. When I do that though, I get this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'messages' is not defined
```

and `messages` has a yellow underline in VSCode saying:

```
"messages" is not defined Pylance(reportUnidentifiedVariable)
```

I have no idea what else to try.

Here is the code for the cog:

```
import discord
from discord.ext

class RandomMessage(commands.cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    messages = ["This is one message", "And this is another"]

    @commands.command()
    async def randmsg(self, ctx, messages):
        await ctx.send(random.choice(messages))
    
    @commands.command()
    async def addmsg(self, ctx, messages, *, message):
        messages.append(message)
        await ctx.send(f"{message} was added to the list of messages.")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(RandomMessage(client))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote yourself, if you add `messages` as an argument, it is expecting user input. To reference the `messages` variable you need to call it with `self.messages` because its in a class. `self` represents the instance of the class.

This here should work:

```
messages = ["This is one message", "And this is another"]

@commands.command()
async def randmsg(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send(random.choice(self.messages))
   
@commands.command()
async def addmsg(self, ctx, *, message):
    self.messages.append(message)
    await ctx.send(f"{message} was added to the list of messages.")
```